# content are moving outside of "container", looking for possible solution

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap V 3.

In below code I have a "container" and inside that 1 row with some fix height (need vertical scroll when content is more).

But the last row always show me outside the container. Please suggest possible solution. Thanks!

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="border:1px solid #cecece;">
                    <div class="row" style="height:40%;min-height:100px;">
                        --content--
                    </div>
                </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Please create a fiddle of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're floating those div's because you haven't posted you code.

If you did this, try making a clearfix on the `:after` of or putting `overflow: hidden` on the parent element, `container-fluid`.

```
.container-fluid {  overflow: hidden;  }
```

or

```
.container-fluid:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container-fluid" style="border:1px solid #cecece;">
                    <div class="row" style="height:40%;min-height:100px;">
                   <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4" style="border:1px solid red;background:#f7f7f7;text-align:center;">train</div> 
                      <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4" style="border:1px solid red;background:#f7f7f7;text-align:center;">train</div>
                       <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4" style="border:1px solid red;background:#f7f7f7;text-align:center;">train</div>
                    </div>
   <div class="row" style="height:40%;min-height:100px;">
                   <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4" style="border:1px solid red;background:#f7f7f7;text-align:center;">train</div> 
                      <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4" style="border:1px solid red;background:#f7f7f7;text-align:center;">train</div>
                       <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4" style="border:1px solid red;background:#f7f7f7;text-align:center;">train</div>
                    </div>
   <div class="row" style="height:40%;min-height:100px;">
                   <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4" style="border:1px solid red;background:#f7f7f7;text-align:center;">train</div> 
                      <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4" style="border:1px solid red;background:#f7f7f7;text-align:center;">train</div>
                       <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4" style="border:1px solid red;background:#f7f7f7;text-align:center;">train</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I hope your answer is here..